# htaccess specific url change from xx.com/course?id=1 to xx.com/1 in core php using <a> tag

Tags: php

I want to change URL for example http://localhost/mysite/index.php?page=about will become http://localhost/mysite/about

User

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service; you are supposed to show the results of your own research and attempts when asking, and not just give us an “I want”.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```